# How to track the distance when user running/ walking

Tags: java, android, eclipse, distance, tracking

Im currently doing an apps that can track running distance.
My idea is when i click start, i will record the position that i start running, then when i click stop, it will record the position that i end my running. Then calculate the distance between this 2 point.
I don't know why my distance result keep showing me 0km no matter how i run. Please help me see if gt any problems~

```css
package com.example.ifitness;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

```html
public class calorieburn extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener{
private GoogleMap map;
private Location startLocation;
private Location endLocation;
private double latA;
private double longA;
private double latB;
private double longB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calorieburn);
        SetupMap();           
        
        Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
      latA = startLocation.getLatitude();
      longA = startLocation.getLongitude();
      
      TextView distance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance);
      distance.setText("0 km");
      
      TextView calorie = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calorie);
      calorie.setText("0 cal");
      
      
   }
  });
        
        Button stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        
        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      
      latB = endLocation.getLatitude();
      longB = endLocation.getLongitude();
   
      TextView distance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.distance);
      distance.setText(String.valueOf(distance(latA,longA,latB,longB)+ "km"));
      
      TextView calorie = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.calorie);
      calorie.setText(String.valueOf(distance(latA,longA,latB,longB)+ "cal"));
   }
  });            
              
 }

    public double calories(double distance){
     
     double calories = 0;
     calories = distance * 100;
     return calories;
    }

    public static void distanceBetween(){
     
    }
    
    public double distance(double lat,double lng,double latitude,double longtitude){
     Location locA = new Location("locA");
  locA.setLatitude(lat);
  locA.setLongitude(lng);
  
  Location locB = new Location("locB");
  locB.setLatitude(latitude);
  locB.setLongitude(longtitude);
  
  double distance = locA.distanceTo(locB);
  
  return distance;
 
    }
    
 private void SetupMap() {
  if (map == null){
      // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml 
      SupportMapFragment mf = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        
      // get google map from the fragment
      map = mf.getMap();                               
     }
    
    if (map !=null ){
    
     // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
     map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
     
     // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
     LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
     Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
     criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
     String bestprovider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria,false);
     String provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
     
     if (provider == null){
      onProviderDisabled(provider);
     }
     
     // Getting Current Location
     Location loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(bestprovider);
     if (loc != null){
      onLocationChanged(loc);
      
     }
     
     map.setOnMapLongClickListener(onLongClickMapSettings());
    }
  }

 private OnMapLongClickListener onLongClickMapSettings() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return new OnMapLongClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onMapLongClick(LatLng arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub   
    Log.i(arg0.toString(), "User Long CLicked");
   }
  };   
 }
 
 @Override
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  // Getting latitude of the current location
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
 
        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
 
        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
 
        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
 
        // Zoom in the Google Map
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));
  
 }

 private void makeUseOfNewLocation(Location location) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }

 @Override
 public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }

 @Override
 public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }

 @Override
 public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }
 
 
}
```

Comment: That's really not the right formula for working out a distance.

Comment: even with this formula
Location locA = new Location("locA");
     locA.setLatitude(lat);
     locA.setLongitude(lng);
     
     Location locB = new Location("locB");
     locB.setLatitude(latitude);
     locB.setLongitude(longtitude);
     
     double distance = locA.distanceTo(locB);

i also cant get the result

Comment: Please, Wendy, you shouldn't change all the code in your question after someone answers it.  It just makes the answer wrong, and the whole question becomes useless to any future users of the site.  I am now deleting my answer, since you have made it invalid.